# Can you help me find this unit vector?

Tags: analytic-geometry

> The vectors $a = (1,1,1)$ and $b = (−1, −1, −1)$ are given. Determine the unit vector $c$ such that $\angle (a, c) = \frac \pi 6$ and that the area of ​​the parallelogram constructed over the vectors $b$ and $c$ is equal to $\sqrt2.$

So I tried solving this like:

$$P=|b \times c|=\sqrt2 \Rightarrow b \times c=(y-z, z-x, x-y)$$

$$|c|=1 \Rightarrow x^2 +y^2+c^2=1$$

and $$∡ (a, c) = π / 6 \Rightarrow ac=|a||c|\cdot \cos ∡ (a, c)$$

And with this I got 3 equations but i really don't know if this is correct or not. Can you help me solve this, I need it for my homework.

Comment: Vectors $a$ and $b$ seem to be aligned and for $c$ unitary the area for the paralellogram should be $3/2$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't believe there are any solutions.

Comment: I got three equations the first one
(1) x^2+y^2+z^2=1 i got it from |c|=sqrt( x^2+y^2+z^2)=1  

(2) x+y+z=3/2  from a*c=|a||c|⋅cos∡(a,c) => (x+y+z)/sqrt(3)=sqrt(3)/2  

and (3) (y-z)^2+(z-x)^2+(x-y)^2=2 i got it from P=|bxc|=sqrt(2) bxc=(y-z,x-z,x-y)

But it doesn't look me right, i think I made mistake somwhere so please if you can help me it would mean a lot to me. Thank you all.

Comment: @Sunshine Check the input data for the problem.

Comment: @user This question was even on exam few years ago. It cant be mistake in the input data. But thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

As currently stated, the problem has no solution, indeed vectors $a$ and $b$ are aligned with lenght $\sqrt 3$ therefore for any vactor $c$ such that $\angle (a, c) = \frac \pi 6$ we have that the area of the parallelogram is

$$A=\sqrt 3 \cdot 1 \sin\left(\frac \pi 6\right)= \frac 3 2\neq \sqrt 2$$

Comment: But area of paralelogram is for vectors b and c not for a and c and their angle:             P= ({\sqrt 3})*1*sin∠(b,c)={\sqrt 2}  => sin∠(b,c)=sqrt(2)/sqrt(3)   I understand that  |a|=|b|= sqrt(3) but how are they aligned?

Comment: @Sunshine We have that $a=-b \iff a+b=0$ which means that they are aligned.

Comment: I am little disappointed, because it doesn't have solution. Anyway thank You a lot, You saved me sleepless nights. Sry for my bad English :)

Comment: @Sunshine You are welcome! Check for the errata corrige of the book. Bye